# How to get a running sum on HTML table?

Tags: javascript

I searching a solution for give the running sun to a editable html table, like a spreadsheet:

[image: Table]

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried?

Comment: Hi, could you please provide the code you currently have? for what I understand, you want to calculate the sum of the previous and the current value in the row from the column cost, and show it on the column "running sum" using an editable HTML table and javascript. There are many ways to do this, we can guide you on correcting your mistakes over your code, but not do it for you.

Comment: This is a reasonable question.  There may be a simple JS library that has basic spreadsheet functionality, e.g. summing a `<tr>` or columns within a `<table>`, though I don't know.  +1.  I would not attempt a home-baked solution before exploring that possibility.  And am shocked at the downvotes.

Answer (score 0):

Hi here is a basic example of what you want using :

1. The HTML content editable property.
2. A css class to append a focusout event to the table cell.
3. A simple loop to sum all values when one value changes.

```js
$('#tbodyTest >tr').on('focusout', 'td.editable', (e) => {
  let target = $(e.target),
    parent_row = $(e.target).closest('tr'),
    previous_row = parent_row.prev();
  setTimeout(() => {
    if (!isNaN(target.text())) {
  $('#tbodyTest').children('tr').each((i,e)=>{
      $(e).find('td').last().text(Number($(e).find('td:eq(2)').text()) +Number($(e).prev().find('td').last().text()))
    })
    }else{
      target.text("0");
  parent_row.find('td').last().text("0");
  $('#tbodyTest').children('tr').each((i,e)=>{
  $(e).find('td').last().text(Number($(e).find('td:eq(2)').text()) +Number($(e).prev().find('td').last().text()))
})
    }
  })
})
```

```css
.editable {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="test" border=1>
  <thead>
    <th>date</th>
    <th>desc</th>
    <th>cost</th>
    <th>running sum</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="tbodyTest">
    <tr>
      <td>01-01-2019</td>
      <td>a</td>
      <td class="editable" contenteditable='true'>1000</td>
      <td>1000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>01-02-2019</td>
      <td>a</td>
      <td class="editable" contenteditable='true'></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>01-03-2019</td>
      <td>a</td>
      <td class="editable" contenteditable='true'></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>01-04-2019</td>
      <td>a</td>
      <td class="editable" contenteditable='true'></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Keep in mind that this is a basic example and you will probably add more stuff according to your needs since your ask is simple as well.

Hope it helps

Comment: Hi Stan, Tks for this, that exactly what I nedd. I have another questions for you. I would like to change de color of the result if is negatif. Again TKS you so much for your help.

Comment: @Real compare the result, do a if statement with this comparision,  myresult is lower than 1 , then parent_row.children("td").last().css("background","red")  else do something else

Answer (score 0):

Anyone still looking to this.

```js
$('tr').each(function(index, el) {
  if (index == 0) {
    $(this).find('.running-balance').text($(this).find('.amount').text());
  } else {
    var prevRow = $(this).prev();
    var prevBalance = Number(prevRow.find('.running-balance').text());
    var currentAmount = Number($(this).find('.amount').text());
    var newBalance = prevBalance + currentAmount;
    $(this).find('.running-balance').text(newBalance.toFixed(2));
  }
});
```

```css
td,
th {
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Description</th>
      <th>Amount</th>
      <th>Running Balance</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>a</td>
      <td class="amount">100</td>
      <td class="running-balance"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>b</td>
      <td class="amount">150</td>
      <td class="running-balance"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>c</td>
      <td class="amount">125</td>
      <td class="running-balance"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>d</td>
      <td class="amount">205</td>
      <td class="running-balance"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>e</td>
      <td class="amount">50</td>
      <td class="running-balance"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```